# The loop iterates only once in this code while in another code it iterates properly

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, sizeof

Why is the loop running only once in this code?

```
 // Example program
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    int n=5;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(a);i++)
    {
        cout<<"mohit jain"<<endl;
    }
      return 0;
    }
```

While in the code the loop iterate five-time?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a[5];
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(a);i++)
{
    cout<<"mohit jain"<<endl;
}
  return 0;
}
```

So please tell me the rightful reason why it iterates once in the first code while iterating five times in the second code.

Comment: VLAs are non-standard in C++.

Comment: Please note the VLA is an optional extension. It's size is runtime-determined, so the type is different.

Comment: Unless you have a broken compiler or are doing something very wrong they should both iterate 20 times (assuming sizeof(int) == 4). See: http://ideone.com/2PUZRR

Comment: Try printing value of `sizeof(a)` in both cases and then figure out the difference if any.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `const int n = 5` instead.
By default C++ does not allow dynamic size arrays (and in this case it is dynamic, because `n` is non-const). It works only because your compiler uses some kind of extension to allocate an array in this case, e.g. gcc's variable arrays.

So, the first example is non-standard C++ code and the reason why `sizeof` returns 1 instead of `5 * sizeof(int)` lies in the compiler-specific implementation of the extension.

BTW, the second loop runs `5 * sizeof(int)` times (20 times on most systems), not 5.

Comment: They both run 20 times, on any current version of g++.

Comment: please correct your answer and make it more general since it will not necessarily run 20 times, it depends on the `sizeof(int)`. + In case of the OP, the result of `sizeof` may be implementation defined, so even 5 times maybe the actually returned value by `sizeof(a)`

Comment: They both run 20 times also with Visual Studio v100 and v120 compilers, supposing sizeof(int) = 4. Moreover first code is illegal for that compiler unless you don't declare n as a const variable.

Comment: I tried several compilers and was able to reproduce Mohit's problem on this website: http://cpp.sh/

Comment: @AlexPetrenko: it looks like the version of g++ in use at cpp.sh (4.9.2 - quite old) has a bug in this regard - adding `const` fixes it for some reason. Current versions of g++ do not have this problem.